# Need guidance with SQL/Java syntax specifically to make a connection between a composite key and a primary key

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

While I know that this is not the recommended course of action, I'm developing an application that stores data to later be converted into a fiscal note, which means I made one table to store the product's data and the other to merge it with the client's data/data of emission, etc.

The application is organized in a way that the code for the sale is being correctly inserted into the DB, but the tables aren't completely connected, as I couldn't figure a way of doing it besides just inserting two equal values into two different tables without any foreign keys (because you can't update child columns if I understood correctly), it works like this:

User selects a product (and the amount) and a client,
SaleId gets inserted once in the final table,
but on the product table, the SaleId gets inserted (product amount) times.

Ex: FinalTable SaleID: 1 / ProductTable SaleID: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 (Assuming there are 5 products with that code)

What I want to know is if there is a way to connect the two tables using a foreign key or something like that, I totally understand why it is not recommended, but that's precisely why I'm asking for different opinions on the topic.

Comment: *Ex: FinalTable SaleID: 1 / ProductTable SaleID: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 (Assuming there are 5 products with that code)* Show table data state after insertion. As table-formatted text. *the tables aren't completely connected, as I couldn't figure a way of doing it besides just inserting two equal values into two different tables without any foreign keys* These statements are not related. And the reason of FK absence is absolutely unclear. You have classic 1:N relation.

Comment: I was using a Foreign key to reference the SaleID (composite key) from the ProductTable, but that way it wouldn't let me insert the same value into ProductTable, because it does not accept duplicates, I could only manage to make it work by removing it, I'm quite new on the DB field, sorry if for not being clear.

Comment: You create FK with wrong direction. It must be created in the table on the side `N` of the relation, not on the side `1`. On the side `1` the index by column to be referred to must exist (by separate column, or this column must be a prefix in composite index).

Comment: I see, thank you very much